# Correct way of implemeting login in ASP.NET page

Tags: asp.net, authentication, implementation

Please consider this two ways of login in ASP.NET page:

1. Connect with windows authentification:

   ```
   _con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=True");
   _con.Open();
   ```

   After that we may check if Username provided by cusromer exists in Users table, so that login was successful.
2. Or connect using username and password:

   ```
   _con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;");
   _con.Open();
   ```

   After that only users which provided valid username and password can connect to DB and fetch data, that involves creating a user in DB for every customer.

Questions:

1. Are these ways of implementing login in ASP.NET page correct?
2. If yes, what way you'd prefer, first one or second one?
3. Any better ways of implementing login in ASP.NET page?

Comment: I think I mis-read the question.  The title indicates you're asking about **logging into a website**, but the code snippets indicate **connecting to a database**.  They're two different things.  Are you specifically wondering about the best way to connect to the database?

Comment: @David Stratton: you provided good links about Forms authentification, which I have already read :). The question is about a bit different thing, please look at this link: http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/an-overview-of-forms-authentication-cs . Then find implementation of LoginButton_Click.  Notice that this implementation in order to be complete needs to somehow connect to database and fetch users Login and password. So the question is about correct way of checking validaty of customer's provided login and password with login and password from a database. What is best way to do this?

Comment: Then my answer does not apply.  See the other two answers, both of which answer your actual questio better.

Comment: @David Stratton: ok, thank! But actually your post was usefull even not applicable :), I found what is oauth, and read good article, so thanks about this :) I repost links: http://oauth.net/, http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/11/your-internet-drivers-license.html .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I wouldn't use a connection string for each user. Otherwise you'll have the extra headache of maintaining logins in both your app and sql server.

Use one login for your application, and use either your own login check or use ASP.NET membership provider: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx

Answer (score 2):

In particular method 2 is really bad news, as you would have to create a SQL login for each and every user of your website.

I'm not sure if I you really want to give each and every user access to your database, so really be careful with that.

If you can use Windows Authentication that solves most of your (authentication) problems in one go, and you really won't have to do much to get that running.